# How to loop over every row of streaming query dataframe in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub, azure-data-lake-gen2

I Have a Streaming query as below picture, now for every row i need to loop over dataframe do some tranformation and save the result to adls. Can anyone help me how to loop over streaming df. I m struck.

[image]

Comment: what kind of transformation do you need to apply?

Comment: I will receive a json as message with around 1000 keys and values, now i need to filter unncessary keys from json and then convert the json to dataframe and save it back to adls. @alex

Answer (score 0):

Please check the link for details on foreach and foreachbatch
[using-foreach-and-foreachbatch](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch)

You can perform operations inside the function process_row() when calling it from pyspark.sql.DataFrame.writeStream interface

```
def process_row(row):
    # Write row to storage (in your case adls)
    pass

ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = connectionString 
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc.jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs. 
EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString) df = spark.readStream. \ 
format("eventhubs").options(**ehConf).load()
df_new = df.writeStream.foreach(process_row).start()
```

Comment: In the process_row function , as you said i was using spark.createDataFrame() before saving. Its throwing error as ---
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.    ----> Any Idea how to do this ??

Comment: @KoradaGanesh the process_row() function will run on the worker nodes and you should write code inside only to perform operations on single row. Spark context 'spark' and 'sc' are not available on the worker nodes

Comment: ,So i will receive dictionary object from event hub , which contains around 100 keys. So from this object i need to keep only 10 keys and make a dataframe from dict with 10 keys and write it to adls. this is my requirement. DO you have any idea how i can do this ?